# mark point on figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

From this Matlab code :

```
a=[1:.001:5] ;
f=(1./a)-(a-1) ;
plot(a,f)
```

I want to mark the point when `(f==0)` on the figure, assuming the value of `a` is unknown and I should take it from the figure.

I want it to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the command '*text*' http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html as follows,

```
[~,idx] = find(abs(f)<1e-3);
text( a(idx(1)), f(idx(1)), 'here we touch/cut/cross x-axis')
```

Comment: thanx ,, but is there any command that determine the point when f==0 on the graph

Comment: You need to find that point, in my example, using 'find' to recover the index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use interp1 to find the point where f = 0;

```
a_for_f_equal_zero = interp1(f, a, 0);
line(a_for_f_equal_zero, 0, 'marker', 'o', 'color', 'r', 'linestyle', 'none')
x_lim = get(gca, 'XLim');
y_lim = get(gca, 'YLim');
line(a_for_f_equal_zero * [1,1], [y_lim(1), 0], 'color', 'k') % vertical line 
line([x_lim(1), a_for_f_equal_zero], [0,0],  'color', 'k') % horizontal line
```